# Install pip on OS X : Couldn't find index page for 'pytest' (maybe misspelled?)

Tags: python, macos, pip

I want to install pip in order to install TensorFlow following those [instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac).
When I'm trying the first instruction `sudo easy_install pip` I get this:

```
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 9.0.1
Adding pip 9.0.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip3.5 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip3 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Processing dependencies for pip
Searching for pytest
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pytest/
Couldn't find index page for 'pytest' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for pytest
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pytest')
```

I've tried several things so far found on the net but as I didn't understand everything I can't really explain all about it.
I know I have Python 2.710 and Python 3.6.3 installed and maybe they are interfering?

I'd be glad if you could help me with that issue and even more if you could explain me what I'll be doing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience it is better to not install Python packages into your system installation. This is what you are doing with the `sudo` to elevate your rights.

Install a separate and more recent Python 2.7 using OS X Homebrew.

Once Homebrew is installed you can create a virtualenv, activate it, and then continue with the instructions.

Comment: Alright I have upgraded Python 2.7 to version 2.7.14 (not with Homebrew as it didn't work... I went on the official website and download the package).
Then I tried to install virtualenv with Homebrew but it doesn't work neither. How does it work?

Comment: Well it didn't solve my issue yet. How does it work?

Comment: Did you create a virtualenv from the new brew based python, activate it, and follow the instructions you posted?

Comment: I am on mobile and it shows me more of your first comment only later. If you failed to install brew you should get that solved first. There are Q&A regarding brew install on this site to follow.

Comment: Finally after upgrading to Python 2.7.14 it worked. I also have used a better WiFi connection maybe this has helped? Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!